# Is a python script aware of its stored location path?

Tags: python

```
/home/bar/foo/test.py:
```

I am trying `test.py` to print `/home/bar/foo` irrespective of from where I run the script from:

```
import os
def foo():
  print os.getcwd()
```

test run:

```
[/home/bar $] python /home/bar/foo/test.py        # echoes /home/bar
[/tmp $] python /home/bar/foo/test.py             # echoes /tmp
```

`os.getcwd()` not the function for the task. How can I get this done otherwise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os.path
p = os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `__file__` variable will contain the location of the individual Python file.

Comment: This won't give the absolute path though, which is what I think OP is looking for. It will basically return the relative path from where it is being called.

Answer (score 2):

If the script is somewhere in your path, then yes, you can strip it from sys.argv

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           
import sys
import os
print sys.argv
print os.path.split(sys.argv[0])

dan@somebox:~$ test.py
['/home/dan/bin/test.py']
('/home/dan/bin', 'test.py')
```

Comment: Note that this approach relies on the behavior of the invoking program. When that program is a decent shell (bash, zsh), it will work; but any other `exec`-ing program may set `argv[0]` of your script to whatever value it decides.

Comment: I hate to pick on ulidtko, but the interpreter is the one that populates sys.argv for the Python program, not its parent process.  If I execute "/usr/local/bin/python myprogram.py" in the shell, sys.argv[0] is "myprogram.py", not "/usr/local/bin/python".

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you can use `__file__` attribute of module objects.

Although, I'd like to note that in general, not-Python, case, you could've use `sys.argv[0]` for the same purpose. It's a common convention among different shells to pass full absolute pathname of the program through `argv[0]`.

Comment: @wberry, yes, thanks to Python importing mechanism, the exact location is accessible. But in the *global general* (non-python), a process can't reliably determine location of its binary, or script file. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I think you are correct for compiled binaries on Unix.  So the Python interpreter does not know its own location.  But the top-level Python program, and its modules, can learn theirs from the interpreter using __ file __ and the sys and inspect modules.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in a file and then run it.

```
import inspect, os.path

def codepath(function):
  path = inspect.getfile(function)
  if os.path.isabs(path): return path
  else: return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path))

print codepath(codepath)
```

My tests show that this prints the absolute path of the Python script whether it is run with an absolute path or not.  I also tested it successfully when importing it from another folder.  The only requirement is that a function or equivalent callable be present in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
print sys.path[0]
```

This will give you the full path to your script every time, whereas `__file__` will give you the path that was used to execute the script. `'sys.path'` always has the path to the script as the first element, which allows one to always be able to import other .py files in the same directory.